# Width property does not works

Tags: css, wordpress

I am working on this website https://fortlauderdaleflorida.realestate/.
It has a search button in front of search bar. I am trying to fix its width but it does not works at all. I have written this code:

```
.idx-omnibar-form button{
    width: 20%;
    padding: initial;
    border-radius: 30px;
    background-color: rgba(33,40,11,0.93);
    color: white;
    font-size: 22px;
}
```

Now all the properties are working execpt the width and padding property. I have put it in css plugin, in theme's css portion and also in elementor's css portion but it does not worked from anywhere. Please tell me how reduce its width and put some margin between text box and button. I do not have access to back end files.

Comment: inspecting your code  ..  seems that you have redefined  width from 20% to 40%  ..  check of your css files hierarchy

Comment: Appears to be working for me, when I inspect and change old values. You have set width to 40% and padding to inherit.

Comment: Actually I am using shortcode for this and width and padding is by default. I am trying to change this but not able to do so. As this is hosted with wordpress.com so can not access the back end files.

Comment: Yes it changed when we do it with inspect element but it does not work when we write it as css code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

looking at the code it seems that another file have set the width and padding and used the `!important` property on them. Thus, even with the correct hierarchy, you will not be able to override the values of width and height, so you'll need to also use `!important` to override these, it's not best option, but since you don't have access it's the only solution.

```
.idx-omnibar-form button{
    width: 20%!important;
    padding: initial!important;
    border-radius: 30px;
    background-color: rgba(33,40,11,0.93);
    color: white;
    font-size: 22px;
}
```

Make sure you only have this added in Theme CSS or another place where it can take effect, so it is not added multiple time.

Answer (score 0):

Looking through your site and CSS files I found that this is a problem with hierarchy. CSS works its way from top to bottom. Whichever comes last is most likely to be used. And it seems that the CSS from your `idx-omnibar` comes in last. It is loaded at the bottom of the document.

Check if you can configure the placement of the `idx-omnibar` CSS file in your document to make it load on the top of your page. There might be a plugin setting.

However, it is possible to use other features of CSS to work around this, such as `specificity`. The more specific a CSS selector is, the more likely it will be used. Unless another selector with the same specificity comes after it. Read more about this in [this article on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The article you have mentioned tells me about !important and it worked for me.

Comment: I would recommend that you use `!important` only if no other solution works. Overwriting `!important` can be problematic and difficult.

Comment: Yes there is no other solution other than that as I have to access to back end to change it from there.